# Can I change where my /home folder is located?

Tags: 12.04, home-directory

I want to make my /home folder on a separate partition on my harddrive. How can I do that, if there is a way?

Comment: `/home` folder is in your hard drive, anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that you want your /home folder on a separate partition on your harddisk? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

The basic steps are as follows:

- Setup your new partition
- Backup and edit your `fstab` to mount the new partition as `/media/home` (just for the time being) and reboot.
- Use `rsync` to migrate all data from `/home` into `/media/home`.
- Edit `fstab` again so the new partition mounts as `/home` instead of `/media/home` but not reboot just yet.
- Move `/home` to `/old_home` and reboot
- Delete `/old_home`.